# Adding static library in a project, showing red marked

Tags: iphone, static-libraries

I am trying to add a custom static library in an project, it is being added but indicating red which means file is missing i think. Why is so. Below is the image. Why so, please guide.

[image]

Please guide for the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did you copied the adSdkProject.xcodeProj? is it open source? if yes then send the link

Comment: No, i created it, it's a dummy library.

Comment: run your adSdkProject.xcodeProj and add the product Link binary with library

Comment: Does it have issues when u execute it?

Comment: app may crash when it will try to access that library, instead of asking just run it and check either is it having issue or not....

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `libadSdkProject.a` manually in the project, but you have to build the `adSdkProject.xcodeProject` separately, it will make the product  `libadSdkProject.a`, then you can add that product `(libadSdkProject.a)`in your Project's Link binary with library.

Comment: I did this way only, created separate project of static library, then added that to the another project as target and then added libadSdkProject.a manually after that it shows this red thing.

Comment: 1:did you added the search path of your library? 
Go the the search path, header search path and the path where headers exists of that library....
clean run your project....<br>
2:when you link binary with libraries, it adds the .a file in your project. currently it is not showing .a file in your project, so it is not libadSdkProject.a file is not included in your project.